# Enum is Reference Type or Value Type?

Tags: .net, enums, value-type, reference-type

I used Enum property in my [EntityFramework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/ef) 5 class,
but in the database this field is nullable. Visual studio gives the error that this property must be a nullable property. My question is: is Enum a reference type or a value type?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

`System.Enum` is a reference type, but any *specific* enum type is a value type. In the same way, `System.ValueType` is a reference type, but all types inheriting from it (other than `System.Enum`) are value types.

So if you have an enum `Foo` and you want a nullable property, you need the property type to be `Foo?`.

Comment: Worth noting that `Foo?` is sugar for `System.Nullable<Foo>` and that `Nullable` is also a value type.

Answer (score 16):

If you do `myEnum.SomeValue` it will be a value type.

Answer (score 5):

suppose we have enum

```
public enum eCategory
{
    health ,        
    Weapon
}
```

and a type of eCategory such as :-

```
eCategory currentcategory;
```

then currentcategory is of value type

Answer (score 3):

```
public enum TestReferenceOrValue
{
    one, two, three    
}
var a = TestReferenceOrValue.one;
var b = a;
b = TestReferenceOrValue.three;
```

If enums are by reference, changing `b` affects `a`
`Console.Write(a);` → one
`Console.Write(b);` → three

a great online tool for cSharp => http://csharppad.com/

Comment: I downvoted for your display of erroneous programming conventions. Enum fields should start with an uppercase letter.

Comment: The above code sample is unhelpful since it would act the same **regardless of whether `TestReferenceOrValue` was a reference type or value type**. `var a = "a";
var b = a;
b = "b";
Console.Write(a);
Console.Write(b);` shows that strings (and every type) act that way - and `string` is a reference type. That is because you are *overwriting* the b variable, not *altering* the object to which it points.