# Java to C#, tricky Generic unchecked type

Tags: java, c#

In C# I want to be able to write

FooEnum f = fromValue(typeof(FooEnum), 42);

where fromValue returns MyEnum and FooEnum extends MyEnum.

I am converting some Java code to C#.  The Java code has

```
  static <T extends MyEnum> T fromValue(Class<T> c, int value) { 
      return (T)fromInnerValue(c, value);
  }
```

This means that if we can write

```
  FooEnum f = fromValue(FooEnum.class, 42);
```

Which will return a FooEnum without the need for an explicit casts.  (This happens a lot so is worthwhile.)  It is "unchecked" in the narrow sense that if fromInnerValue was to return a BarEnum instead of a FooEnum we would get a runtime cast exception instead of a compile time one.

In C#/.Net System.Type does not appear to be generic.  So the function definition becomes

```
  static T fromValue<T>(System.Type c, int value) where T : Enum {
      return (T)fromInnerValue(c, value);
  }
```

That compiles, but with Type rather than Type, so it does not really know what T is at compile time.  Then a call

```
  FooEnum f = fromValue(typeof(FooEnum), 42);
```

fails with "Type cannot be inferred from its arguments".

```
  FooEnum f = fromValue<FooEnum>(typeof(FooEnum), 42);
```

works but has the verbosity I am trying to avoid.  I think it means that fromValue has an actual run time parameter T as there is no type erasure in C#.  But we have the type as that first parameter, c.  But it needs to somehow be the Generic type.

Or can we go the other way in C# and make
FooEnum f = fromValue(42);
work?

(If it cannot be done then I would be inclined to forget about Generics and just write

FooEnum f = (FooEnum)fromInnerValue(typeof(FooEnum), 42);
)

Thoughts?

Comment: Enum in c# is not a class but a special construct. It seems a little like you are going down the wrong track

Comment: Can you show what `fromInnerValue` does? I'm surprised that `(T)fromInnerValue(c, value);` compiles. Also, why does `MyEnum` change to `Enum` in the C# version?

Comment: Try  `static T fromValue<T>(int value) where T : Enum {  return (T)fromInnerValue(typeof(T), value); }`. You can call it with `FooEnum f = fromValue<FooEnum>(42);`

Comment: "Which will return a FooEnum without the need for an explicit casts" - what is `(T)fromInnerValue(c, value)` then? Seems pretty darn explicit to me...

Comment: Anyway, assuming you are using an actual enum ,just cast... it can't be easier (myenum)42... unless you want to validate it

Comment: FooEnum is not and Enum; otherwise it would have been called Enum if it was an Enum!  But FooEnum is a Java Enum like object, but unlike Java it is extensible at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless there is something special going on you should just be able to just do a cast

```
var f = (FooEnum)42;
```

If you absolutely want a generic method it should be possible to use

```
public static T FromValue<T>(int value) where T :  Enum
        => (T)Enum.ToObject(typeof(T), value);
```

See [how to cast an int to an enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29482/how-can-i-cast-int-to-enum)

Comment: typeof(T) is the trick.  My compile-time-generics-only  Java mindset prevented me from thinking of that.

Comment: FooEnum is not and Enum; otherwise it would have been called Enum if it was an Enum!  But FooEnum is a Java Enum like object, but unlike Java it is extensible at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you have an int that you want to cast to an enum member.

Let me explain the problem.
In java an enum is a class, so you cant cast (rightfully) an int to a class.
In .NET an enum is also a class, but its values are primitives (ValueType).
The default type of an enum item is int.
You can refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14561338/enum-is-reference-type-or-value-type) for more information.

And since a .NET enum is an it, you can simply do

```cs
MyEnum val = (MyEnum) 42;
```

A compile time error wont raise here because if you pass BarEnum instead of FooEnum it will still work (and even run),
 all enums are int basiclly (unless specified otherwise).

If for some reason you still want to go with the generic way, you can throw you own exception by checking if the value is defined in the enum.

```cs
static FromValue<T>(int value) where T : enum
{
  if(!Enum.IsDefined<T>(value))
     throw new Exception("This is awkward ..."); // HANDLE VALUE NOT BELONG TO ENUM
  return (T) value;
}
```

Comment: Enum in c# is not a class no matter which way you spin it. Just saying. Anyway the rest was good

Comment: FooEnum is not and Enum; otherwise it would have been called Enum if it was an Enum!  But FooEnum is a Java Enum like object, but unlike Java it is extensible at runtime.