# Inheritance relationship of enum handled by compiler

Tags: c#, inheritance, enums

Implementing some method with parameter of type `Enum` as base class for all enums I was curios whether i need to check the meth's parameter of type `Enum` is `null`.

From experience I know, that enum can't be null, that is also confirmed by compiler: [CS0037](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0037?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS0037)).

In the documentation for [System.Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum?view=netframework-4.7.2) there are sentences like:

> "Enum is the base class for all enumerations in the .NET Framework"

and

> "Note that in all cases, the enumeration does not explicitly inherit
> from Enum; the inheritance relationship is handled implicitly by the
> compiler"

What does mean "inheritance relationship is handled implicitly by the compiler" and if there is an inheritance why I can't assign `null` to the derived class, but I can do it for the base class? Is it something like `object` and `int`?

```
enum SomeEnum { a,b,c }
void SomeMethWantsEnum(Enum someEnum)
{
    if (someEnum == null) return;

    var x = SomeEnum.a;
    someEnum = x;     //OK
    someEnum = null; //OK
    x = null; //Not OK, CS0037
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

enums are very special types very specially handled by the compiler. While it is true that they inherit from `System.Enum` there is another thing which is true, as [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/enum) state:

> Any enumeration type also satisfies the `struct` constraint, which is used to specify that a type parameter is a non-nullable value type.

So the following:

```cs
Enum x = SomeEnum.A;
```

Is actually a [boxing operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing). Check the emitted IL [@sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgNAJiDUAfAAgJgIwFgBQBRAdgK4C2ABAB6kC8pAygPbECmBJAdAIIDcOyAzKSZEyDZqzIBvUhygAhKAGFSAXyA===), it will contain something like:

```
IL_0001: box SomeEnum
```

So you can assign `null` to variable of type `Enum`, but cant to variable of type `SomeEnum`. And that is the reason why you should not work explicitly with `System.Enum` type, in later C#/compiler versions you can work with it as [generic constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters#enum-constraints):

```cs
void SomeMethWantsEnumGen<T>(T someEnum) where T : System.Enum
{
    
}
```

But I would recommend to follow it by `struct` one:

```cs
void SomeMethWantsEnumGen<T>(T someEnum) where T : struct, System.Enum
{
    if (someEnum == null) return; // not ok

    someEnum = null; // not ok
}
```

> What does mean "inheritance relationship is handled implicitly by the compiler"

It means that you don't need to explicitly inherit from `Enum` (actually in C# you can't do it), the compiler will do it for you:

```cs
Console.WriteLine(typeof(SomeEnum).BaseType == typeof(Enum)); // prints true
public enum SomeEnum { A,B,C }
```

> Is it something like `object` and `int`?

Basically yes.

Read also:

- [Enum is Reference Type or Value Type?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14561365/2501279)

Answer (score 0):

enum is the value type. Enum class is a kind of a wrapper over enums supported by the compiler. It's the base point. The rest follows from this. The same is true about arrays and other similar basic data types. Almost all methods in such classes are static.